# I want to know about using required=False in a DRF Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Serializer` (not a `ModelSerializer`):

```py
class DummySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    clas = serializers.CharField()
    section = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

Now, when I give blank input (`""`) to `"section"` while ***PUT***, then I receive an error (though I have given `required=False`) as:

```
{
    "section": [
    "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

I want something like this, If I give both `"clas"` and `"section"` as input then my **`request.data`** should give

```
{"clas": "my_input", "section": "my_input"}
```

and when I give only `"clas"` then **`request.data`** should give:

```
{"clas": "my_input" }
```

Not:

```
{"clas": "my_input", "section": ""}
```

Then in my view, I want to give a default value to a variable based on field `"section"` is there or not as:

```py
var = request.data.get("section", "default_val")
```

can someone pls help here, how to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: you mean you need to set a default value to section if it is not in the request.data? Then you must override the put method. And thus you don't need to set field required to False. because it is actually required.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding `required=False`, you should also add `allow_blank=True` and `allow_null=True` to this field then it accepts an empty input for this field or None value.

By adding these your view will look like this:

```py
class DummySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    clas = serializers.CharField()
    section = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
```

Reference: [**`CharField`** <sup>[drf-docs]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)